# Apache: Reverse proxy with directories

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2, owncloud

I have an Apache server running owncloud on 10.0.0.120:80 and an Apache server for reverse proxy running on 10.0.0.110

### /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPass /owncloud/ http://10.0.0.120:80/
    ProxyPassReverse /owncloud/ http://10.0.0.120:80/
</VirtualHost>
```

### In a browser

**10.0.0.110** and **10.0.0.110/owncloud** currently redirect to **10.0.0.110/index.php**

**10.0.0.110** should resolve to redirect to /var/www/html

**10.0.0.110/owncloud** should redirect to 10.0.0.120:80/index.php

Comment: You forgot to describe what is your actual problem. This isn't a place to share success stories.

Comment: A question might also be appropriate here. [The tour](https://serverfault.com/tour) does mention "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions".